# Getting Instance Of Silex\Application

Tags: php, dependency-injection, silex

I am creating an application with [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) and was wondering if it is possible to somehow get the instance of the `Silex\Application` in a place where I can't do `method_name(Application $application)` in the method parameters?

For example, say I have a private method on a controller that is not an action.  If I put `Application $application` as the parameter, it throws an error saying I need to pass it in.

I would rather not have to manually pass that method in if I don't have to.

Answer (score 4):

There's really only two ways to do it.

a) Pass `Silex\Application` as an argument to the constructor of your class and assign it as an instance variable.

b) Pass the `Silex\Application` to your private method as an argument by hand.

Are you sure you need the full app in your class? The point of dependency injection is to inject dependencies directly, instead of injecting the container (yes, `Silex\Application` extends `\Pimple`, which is a Dependency Injection Container.

Comment: Well, no, I am only looking to get the variable stored in $app['twig'], how would I do that?  I guess I am just unsure on how Pimple knows that an object should be passed into a method through DI or that is it a normal parameter that should be normally passed.

Comment: You cannot automatically pass parameters to method calls. But you can define your controller class as a service and inject twig into the constructor of that class.

Answer (score 2):

From your comment on the other answer, your goal of getting at the Silex/Application is to get at the Twig service there. The way that I've solved getting at the current application in another function for my Silex projects is:

```
use \Silex\Application;
use \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class myController {
  private $a;

  // Route defined as:
  // $app->get('/foo', 'myController::showPage');
  public function showPage(Application $a) {
    $this->a = $a;
    return $this->doAwesome();
  }

  private function doAwesome() {
    $twig = $this->a['twig'];
    return $twig->render('awesomePage.twig');
  }
}
```

Every function that is an endpoint for a route would then save the Application passed to it as a class property, for other functions to get at. It means you have to remember to do `$this->a = $a;` in every function that uses `doAwesome()` (*before* calling `doAwesome()`), but that's the cleanest way I've come up with to tackle that.